# HIghcharts.js addseries doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Ok,

I know this has been asked before, but I still can't figure it out.
The graph does render, but on the second event it does not update.

I am using chart.addSeries in highcharts. 
The chart updates, but no new data is graphed.
Confused.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

A

```
 <script> 
      var executed = false;
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.w-input').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
      var data1=  parseFloat(data.item.test)
      if (!executed) {
        executed = true;
        var Mychart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-area',
                type: 'column',
            },

            title: {
                text: 'test'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: [data.item.test2],
                title: {
                    text: 'test2'
                }
            },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'test3'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 1320,
                color: 'red',
                width: 1,
                label: {
                    text: 'National mean: 1320',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'test1',
            data: [data1],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<em>test1 {point.key}</em><br/>'
            }
        }, {
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'white',
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'test: {point.y}'
            }
        }]

    });
}
else{
  var chart = $('#chart-area').highcharts();
  chart.addSeries({
          name: data.item.test2,
          data: data1
    });
  chart.redraw();
  }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by the second event? the else part doesn't update the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of doing this :

```
 chart.addSeries({
      name: data.item.test2,
      data: data1
});
```

do it like this :

```
chart.addSeries({
      name: data.item.test2,
      data: [data1] // data value should be an array
});
```

if that still not working, make it like this :

```
chart.addSeries({
      name: data.item.test2,
      data: [parseInt(data1)] // in data should be number not string
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that by doing  var data1=  parseFloat(data.item.test) earlier that it wouldn't be an issue.